# Java access clicked JButton's public methods by the MouseEvent

Tags: java

I want to pass/access a parameter to/in my Mouse Event.

```
public class Button extends JButton{
    public int fileID=6;
    public int getButtonID(){
        return fileID;
    }
}

[View.java]
Button1.addMouseListener(controller);

[Controller.java]
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getButtonID()); //not working
    System.out.println(e.getSource().getButtonID()); //not working
```

Basically, what I need is some kind of reference to the clicked button so I can get its fileID. Is this possible? Each button represents a file and I want to give the user the possibility to delete it. Please tell me if there is a better way to obtain the information where the user has clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Dear god thanks so much how did I miss this. Write an answer and I will tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be sure your `Controller` will only ever be added to a `Button`, then why not cast `e.getSource()` to `Button`?

```
((Button) e.getSource()).getButtonID()
```

However, you can also take the `Button` in the constructor of `Controller` and use that (you can't get a `ClassCastException` that way as it has to be a `Button`.)